# Extracting values of raster to points of shapefile crashes ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, memory

I'm running a rather simple script with ArcPy, which extracts values of raster to points of a shapefile:

```
def raster_overlay(input_files):
    for raster in input_files:
        in_shp = "temp/shapefiles/points.shp"
        in_raster = raster
        print in_raster
        ExtractMultiValuesToPoints(in_shp, in_raster, "BILINEAR")

raster_overlay(raster_files)
```

The variable `raster_files` is a list with strings pointing to a number of raster files on the local hard disk.

The shapefile contains around 50 points, and each raster is around 15MB.

If the list of raster is small (more or less <20), everything works as expected. However, I have around 50 raster images. Using the complete list, Python crashes (`"python.exe has stopped working"`) after processing 21 images or so.

The values of the first 20 raster are correctly appended to the shapefile (one column for each raster).

I monitored python.exe in the Windows 7 Resource Monitor. Memory usage of Python starts around 15 MB and then gradually increases to around 700 MB (and then Python crashes). So, memory leakage might be the reason for the crashes (although the PC has 8 GB of RAM).

I tried to include `gc.collect()` and `del in_shp` and `del in_raster` inside the loop, but nothing changed. What else could I try?

---

I just tried changing `BILINEAR` to `NONE`, and the script didn't crash. However, memory usage still increased in the same way (up to around 1.1 GB). And I would like to use bilinear interpolation, so the question is still relevant.

---

Cross-posted [here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/92377-ExtractMultiValuesToPoints-crashes-Python) to the ESRI support. I'll update this question if they can give a solution.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the ExtractMultiValuesToPoints tool. I've had terrible problems in the past with raster processing in arcpy and looping. Try firing this off to ESRI support?

Comment: FYI, your reference to your shapefile should be made out side of your loop.

Comment: You may also want to try writing to a geodatabase feature class instead of a shapefile.  See if that generates the same error.

Comment: Wrap ExtractMultiValuesToPoints with a Try, Except to find the images causing the error, etc.

Comment: @klewis `try: except:` won't catch a hard crash/segfault/core dump like the OP describes.

Comment: @Hornbydd Yes, this tool seems to be terribly buggy. It is supposed to work with multiple raster as input, but there is a bug with multiband raster. So, ironically, the for loop I'm using is a workaround for this other bug with the same tool. One bug leads to another...

Comment: @klewis No single image is causing the error, so I suppose `try, except` won't help

Comment: @artwork21 I just tried your suggestion with the geodatabase, but it resulted in the same error.